# How do I make a background image that fills the screen in Gatsby?

Tags: css, gatsby

I am using Gatsby and I am trying to edit my CSS to give myself a background image that fills the screen then below that I just want a footer. [This](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryhow_css_fullpage_demo.htm) does not have the footer but it is a great example of what I am going for.

I have

```
body, html, #gatsby-focus-wrapper, #__gatsby {
    height: 100%;
}

.landingDiv {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1493663284031-b7e3aefcae8e?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80");
    height: 100%;

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

However, the background does not extend to 100%. I have tried setting parent containers to 100% in order to get this background to expand. This is what it looks like now.

Here is an image showing the width of the
[image]

Here is a Code Pen of this code - https://codepen.io/norogoth/pen/zYwNqWX (updated 3:30pm)

Comment: Add `object-fit: cover;` style to the landingDiv class, this style will adjust the image based on size.

Comment: You need to post a link of the working code.

Comment: @AndyHoffman Are you referring to me? Should I post a link of the jsx?

Comment: If I could test this in a browser, I'd have an answer for you. But without seeing the running code, it's likely not going to happen.

Comment: @AndyHoffman OK I have loaded it with npm start, then saved the html and added the CSS in a Code Pen. https://codepen.io/norogoth/pen/zYwNqWX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use it as a background image, you need to make it's container wider and higher to adapt it to the maximum with and height of the screen. Using relative units may work for you. Something like:

```
.landingDiv {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1493663284031-b7e3aefcae8e?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80");
    height: 100%;

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
 
  /* making it 100% of the total width and height */ 
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

`vh` and `vw` stand for viewport height and viewport width respectively.

Answer (score -1):

Object-fit: cover instead of background-size: cover;